# Ударения в словах

Tags: фонетика

Как объяснить ребенку в первом классе, куда ставятся ударения и как?

Comment: Достаточно самому родителю правильно ставить в словах ударения. Дети на лету схватывают!

Answer (score 5):

Если вы про произносительные нормы, то их и взрослые не знают, не то что дети. Так что в этом смысле действительно надо прежде всего самому не допускать неправильных ударений - и вообще стараться соблюдать правила.

А если про само понятие, то тут единого метода нет. Я совершенно не согласен, что дети все схватят на лету. Надо объяснять. Лично мне понадобилось четыре класса мучений - и только в пятом начал понимать, что это такое, ударение. При том, что интуитивно прекрасно понимал ритм в стихах и понимал разницу, например, между "зАмок" и "замОк".

Итак, первый путь. Попросите ребенка произнести слово громко, но не очень быстро - и ударить кулачком по столу один раз за время произнесения этого слова. Не ошибется - проверено. Это есть **ударения**. Если только сможет понять, на каком слоге он ударит. 
Второй путь. Путь "растянет" в слоге один слог. Тоже почти наверняка это будет ударный. 
Третий.  Разберитесь с ним с омографами типа названных "зАмок" и "замОк". Только тут сложно будет, если он еще не знает про то, что безударные гласные произносятся редуцировано. 
Ну и, наконец, можно попытаться попросить ребенка назвать "самый главный слог", вокруг которого "все остальные". замечено, что дети, когда учатся говорить, обычно начинают произносить самый громкий слог, т.е. ударный. К пяти-шести годам этот принцип еще должен быть "в активном запасе".

*Расскажете потом, помогло ли, ок?*

Answer (score 1):

Как ставить ударение,объясняет учитель, сейчас хорошие развивающие программы, вот например:

- [Ударение | nsportal.ru](http://nsportal.ru/nachalnaya-shkola/russkii-yazyk/udarenie-1)
- [Ударение. Конспект урока русского языка в 1-м классе | festival.1september.ru](http://festival.1september.ru/articles/534485/)
- [Закрепление знаний об ударении и деление слов на слоги. Дикие и домашние животные | logoped.ru](http://logoped.ru/mashnv02.htm)

Если ребёнок не понял, попросите его рассказать, что они делали на уроке,он расскажет, что они рисовали звуковые схемы слов - квадратики на каждую букву, раскрашивали их разными цветами, делили на слоги, среди них выделяли главный слог, на который падает ударение, над ним ставили чёрточку - знак ударения. Дети всегда это понимают, может, Ваш ребёнок отвлёкся,возьмите печатную рабочую тетрадь - там всё нарисовано, он Вам сам объяснит.А куда ставить - это только практика, со временем освоит, делайте с ним каждый день уроки, разговаривайте, поправляйте ошибки - всё встанет на свои места само собой.

Answer (score 0):

Самим говорить правильно и поправлять ребенка, если он ставит неправильные ударения — вот и все.